# Getting unknown attribute error after running successfull migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, database-schema

I get a *"can't write unknown attribute `competition_id` error"* when I try to run these lines of code :

```
notification = Notification.create(
        user:       subscription.tournament.user,
        content:    "#{subscription.user.full_name} a demandé à s'inscrire à #{subscription.tournament.name} dans la catégorie #{subscription.competition.category} ",
        competition: subscription.competition
      )
```

I dont understand as I ran a migration adding competition as a foreign key for notification :

```
    class AddCompetitionToNotification < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_reference :notifications, :competition, index: true, foreign_key: true
      end
    end
```

My schema was also successfully updated and table Notifications seems to have a foreign key competition :

```
  create_table "notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
    t.boolean  "read",           default: false
    t.integer  "convocation_id"
    t.integer  "tournament_id"
    t.integer  "competition_id"
  end

  add_index "notifications", ["competition_id"], name: "index_notifications_on_competition_id", using: :btree
  add_index "notifications", ["user_id"], name: "index_notifications_on_user_id", using: :btree
```

My competition model has the following associations :

```
class Competition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tournament

  has_many :subscriptions, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :notifications, dependent: :destroy
```

My notification model

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :convocation
  belongs_to :tournament
  belongs_to :competition
end
```

Where is this error coming from ?

Comment: Do your `notification` model already have references to `competition`? Show us both models, please.

Comment: Just updated post with notification and competition associations

Answer (score 0):

You could reorder your function call like this:

```
notification = subscription.competition.notifications.new |n|
  n.user_id = subscription.tournament.user.id
  n.content = "#{subscription.user.full_name} a demandé à s'inscrire à #{subscription.tournament.name} dans la catégorie #{subscription.competition.category} "
end 
notification.save!
```